# Verify returned session with Moq

Tags: .net, session, controller, tdd, moq

Im calling a controller method which creates an object and stores it in a session. However, when i try to verify the value of the returned session i cant figure out how to assert it?

Ill provide my code here:

**Test method**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void StartTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        ControllerSetup();

        var setup = new Setup { IsCustomMaxGuess = false, MaxGuesses = 3, IsTimed = true };
        this._mockSession.SetupGet(s => s["session"]).Returns(null);            
        this._mockControllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(this._mockSession.Object);
        this._sut.ControllerContext = this._mockControllerContext.Object;

        // Act
        var result = _sut.Start(setup) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        if (result != null)
            //Verify somehow here?
    }
```

**Controller method GET**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Start(Setup gameSetup)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Secret Number - The Game";

        SecretNumber sn;

        if (Session["session"] == null)
        {
            sn = new SecretNumber(gameSetup);
            Session.Add("session", sn);

            return View("GameView", Session["session"]);
        }
        sn = (SecretNumber)(Session["session"]);
        sn.Initialize();

        return View("GameView", sn);
    }
```

So shortly described it will go into the if-statement as session is null and create an object. Last but not least it will return the session with the view. I wanna verify that it holds the object secretnumber. How?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method cannot be tested in isolation as you are unable to mock the Session object.

If you had used test first development (TDD) along with the ["Dependency Inversion Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (i.e. "Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.") you would not have encountered this problem.

What you need to do first is define an interface for a SessionManager, which will manage interactions with the Session object e.g.

```
public class ISessionManager
{
 public SecretNumber GetSecretNumber();
 public void SetSecretNumber(SecretNumber sn);
}
```

Now you'd refactor your Setup class so that you inject this dependency (read up on "Dependency Injection") e.g.

```
public class Setup
{
 public bool IsCustomMaxGuess; 
 public int MaxGuesses;
 public bool IsTimed;

 private ISessionManager;

 public Setup(ISessionManager sessionManager)
 {
  this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
 }
}
```

Next refactor your Start method to use this dependency:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Start(Setup gameSetup)
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Secret Number - The Game";

    var secretNumber = this.sessionManager.GetSecretNumber();

    if (secretNumber == null)
    {
        sn = new SecretNumber(gameSetup);
        this.sessionManager.SetSecretNumber(secretNumber);

        return View("GameView", secretNumber);
    }

    secretNumber.Initialize();

    return View("GameView", secretNumber);
}
```

Finally with that all done you'll then be able to mock the behaviour of the sessionManager dependency which will enable you to complete your test e.g.

```
this._mockSessionManager.GetSession(s => GetSecretNumber()).Returns(null);
```

And to verify that the session was set within the "if" statement:

```
this._mockSessionManager.Verify(s => SetSecretNumber(It.IsAny<SecretNumber>());
```

You can then also assert that the expected view was returned too.

Note that I have not compiled any of this code so it might be a little rough around the edges!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'll try this out but what I don't like is that I'm going to end up with code only for testing inside the class Setup. e.g. public Setup(ISessionManager sessionManager) etc.

Doesn't seem legit somehow, something tells me its wrong to do so...

Comment: As I said in my answer, in your method you've been coding to concretions instead of abstractions. As you've done this you will be unable to unit test these methods without injecting in your dependencies. What I've suggested is a textbook approach and it is not "wrong to do"!